# All values entered using fields with a list of values are transformed into (0)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, value-list

All values entered using fields with a list of values are transformed into (0) how can we find back the selected values, we lost a lot of work and can't find backups.

[image]

Comment: Hi E.S17 welcome to GIS SE. Check if fieldtype and length is according. Otherwise, provie more information. As it is currently written, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! We entered fields that have a list of values, we could for example choose between 3 options such as: yes/ no/ Maybe, so we had pre-registered in the list of values. for each of our entities we have therefore chosen one of these three options. it worked fine until all selected data was replaced by (0). I do not know if it is clear, sorry it is dificult to explain.

Comment: In what format are your data ? how did you create/define the list of value ? What are the field properties ?

Comment: Best would probably be to share the project with sample data

Comment: I Can't really do that bc their is some private informations and when a try to save just some of the data in a new layer to have a safe sample to share my list of values disappears I just have the fields with no list of values in it anymore. I think it's too complicated thanks a lot for your time. we check all the properties of the fields very thing seems ok the way of creat theme to so maybe it is just a bog.